# create separate list from the same list in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have a list of events and each event has its own UUID. I want to separate the original list into different sublists based on unique UUID.

Ex:

```
"events": [
    {
      "uuid": "14B8396A-3B8A-4708-8698-E4CA058F3285"
    },
    {
      "uuid": "14B8396A-3B8A-4708-8698-E4CA058F3285"
    },
    {
      "uuid": "14B8396A-3B8A-4708-8698-E4CA058F3285"
    },
    {
      "uuid": "14B8396A-3B8A-4708-8698-E4CA058F3286"
    }
  ]
```

I want two Lists like below

```
"events": [
    {
      "uuid": "14B8396A-3B8A-4708-8698-E4CA058F3285"
    },
    {
      "uuid": "14B8396A-3B8A-4708-8698-E4CA058F3285"
    },
    {
      "uuid": "14B8396A-3B8A-4708-8698-E4CA058F3285"
    }
  ]

"events": [
    {
      "uuid": "14B8396A-3B8A-4708-8698-E4CA058F3286"
    }
  ]
```

Comment: same parents not eligible to separate the list. After reading your response you can split it using different condition.

Comment: Use [`groupBy`](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/groupBy.html)  from [`package:collection`](https://pub.dev/packages/collection).